# Where did pandas.stats.moments.ewma go?

Tags: python, pandas

The exponentially-weighted moving average. Can't find it in the latest 1.0.0 or even 0.25.3 versions of pandas. Was there in previous version for python 3.6, now I need it for python 3.8.